Purge an older VirtualBox (7.0) config. Will the current version (7.1) not to be affected?
I keep a residual config of one program on my Linux Mint 22 (Ubuntu Noble base).
This is because I have no idea of what is going to happen by default if I purge the old version, I mean like so:
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-7.0

Will the current version (7.1) not to be affected? Or is it the other way around, i.e. it would delete all virtualbox configuration?
What is the (default) behavior of apt on this action, please?

Here's the list of versions:
$ apt list -a virtualbox-7.1

virtualbox-7.1/unknown,now 7.1.4-165100~Ubuntu~noble amd64 [installed]


$ apt list -a virtualbox-7.0

virtualbox-7.0/unknown 7.0.22-165102~Ubuntu~noble amd64 [residual-config]
virtualbox-7.0/now 7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble amd64 [residual-config]


This will be a comments section:
1st request came from Stephen Kitt, thank you.
$ dpkg -L virtualbox-7.0

Package virtualbox-7.0 does not contain any files (!)


$ ll /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-7.0.*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2024-Sep-12 /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-7.0.list
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2,1K 2024-Jul-11 /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-7.0.postrm

there the .postrm file contains:
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: postrm 155244 2023-01-17 14:15:46Z bird $
## @file
# VirtualBox post remove.
#

# License and other commentary redacted for shortness.


if [ "$1" = "purge" -a ! -f /etc/init.d/vboxdrv ] ; then
  update-rc.d vboxdrv remove >/dev/null || exit $?
fi
if [ "$1" = "purge" -a ! -f /etc/init.d/vboxnet ] ; then
  update-rc.d vboxnet remove >/dev/null || exit $?
fi
if [ "$1" = "purge" -a ! -f /etc/init.d/vboxweb-service ] ; then
  update-rc.d vboxweb-service remove >/dev/null || exit $?
fi
if [ "$1" = "purge" -a ! -f /etc/init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service ] ; then
  update-rc.d vboxballoonctrl-service remove >/dev/null || exit $?
fi

# remove installed extension packs
if [ "$1" = "purge" ]; then
  rm -rf /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/*
fi

# Automatically added by dh_installdebconf/13.14.1ubuntu5
if [ "$1" = purge ] && [ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]; then
    . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
    db_purge
fi
# End automatically added section


exit 0


If the packages are correctly written, this shouldn’t cause any issue. In this particular instance, I haven’t checked but I imagine each package has its own configuration. (Packages that share configuration files need to hand off ownership somehow, or arrange for a third package to own the configuration files.)
You can check this before purging the old package:
dpkg -L virtualbox-7.0

will list the configuration files that remain associated with the package and would be removed by purging it.
A more comprehensive analysis of what purging virtualbox-7.0 would do requires looking at the various files matching /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-7.0.*. This will include the above list of files (if any), and maintainer scripts which might have specific handling for purge.

Editor's Note:
Upon an excellent advice from Stephen Kitt, I inspected the post-remove script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-7.0.postrm). It is sadly written in a way to remove some files without any reflection on VirtualBox version being purged.
Warning:
The extension packs are to be removed upon purge action (/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/*). I had it backed-up, so it was easy to restore.
Thank you Stephen!
